# Login via Jmeter does not work

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, jmeter, stress-testing

Currently I have a page that has been created in .net when I used the HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder and try to record login page, the page is sending a post request but the page is redirect to same. All the parameters are captured but upon submission of the page it redirects back to the same page.

So while playing the recorded stuffs it does not allow to proceed.
The page does not have any API written in back end.

Is there a solution for it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you would need to use [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) element in your test plan. [Here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) you can take a look at simple example.

As a side note I'm not sure if Test Script Recorder is the best option to create test plans, especially when they consists of more complex logic - like authorisation in your case. Please consider writing test plan 'manually'. That can give you better control on what is happening in your scenario and will increase tests maintainability (if done correctly of course)

Comment: I have added some Images can you look into it and have your say on it

Answer (score 1):

Usually .NET web applications assume a couple of dynamic parameters which you need to handle in your test, to wit:

- [VIEWSTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) - page-level state-management
- [EVENTVALIDATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx) - protection from parameters injection

So you need to design your test as follows:

- Open Login page (GET Request)

  - Extract VIEWSTATE and other parameters via i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and store them into JMeter Variables
  - Perform Login (POST Request) - provide credentials and variables from previous step

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for more information and step-by-step instructions.

Comment: I have added some Images can you look into it and have your say in it

Comment: You looks like you need to correlate `__RequestVerificationToken` and `ufprt` parameters instead of viewstate/eventvalidation.

Comment: How can I do that do you have any specific examples for it
Thanks

Comment: I don't have the relevant application to play with right now, in the meantime check out [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter: Part 1 - Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) guide